# javascript works in IE but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am wonder to find document contain all javascript statements works in IE but not in mozilla.

Is there any common document that specify statements works in IE but not in mozilla ?

Comment: Can you write you javascript code and what error occurs in mozila?

Comment: Does http://www.quirksmode.org/ helps?

Comment: What version of IE?  IE6 require changes to your code to look like it would in say Firefox of an equal version.  IE8, IE9, and IE10 do not require those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably not a definitive list, but this document: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ie2mozgd/ gives details of some differences and how to deal with them.