# JavaScript login button works in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, xslt

I have a very simple webpage that asks a user for a login and password and to press a login button. This works perfectly fine in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox, can anyone tell me why or point me in the right direction?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet type="application/xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>

<head>


<title>Test Online Login</title>

<script>

<xsl:if test="VFILE_DATA/LOGGED_IN='TRUE'">

  // Logged in OK so run menu

 document.URL = "http://gla-web01:91/scripts/test.wsc/vfxmlsws.p?" +
                "function=system_blank" +
                "&amp;xsl=Personal.xsl" +
                "&amp;session_key=<xsl:value-of select="VFILE_DATA/SESSION_KEY"/>";

</xsl:if>


function login(){

  // Check to see if login parameters are correct

  document.URL="http://gla-web01:91/scripts/test.wsc/vfxmlsws.p?"+"function=user_login"+"&amp;server_translate=false"+"&amp;xsl_dir=/vfile_test"+"&amp;user_id="+user.value+"&amp;password="+password.value+"&amp;xsl=install_login.xsl";

}

function checkReturnKey(){
    // Test to see if the return key has been pressed
    if ( event.keyCode == 13 )
      login();
  }

</script>
                    <style>
                table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 100%;
                    font-family:calibri
                }

                th, td {
                    text-align: left;
                    padding: 8px;
                    font-family:calibri
                }

                tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #E4E4E4}

                th {
                    background-color: #eedaff;
                    color: black;
                    text-align: left;
                    font: 16px/24px Helvetica Neue, "Arial", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                label {    
                    color: #666;
                    text-align: left;
                    font: 16px/24px Helvetica Neue, "Arial", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
                    width: 100%;

                }
                </style>
</head>


<body>

<div id="title"><h2>Test User Login</h2>
<hr></hr></div>



  User:<input id="user" type="text" onkeypress="checkReturnKey()"/>

  Password:<input id="password" type="password" onkeypress="checkReturnKey()"/>


  <input class="loginButton" type="button" value="Login" onclick="login()"/>  
    <button onclick="login()">Login2</button>
<xsl:if test="VFILE_DATA/LOGGED_IN='FALSE'">
<P/>
Invalid Login

</xsl:if>


</body>

</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see I've tried two different methods of coding the login button, both work in IE but neither in Chrome or FireFox.

I've read several similar topics on this:

[Why this button works in IE but not in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260598/why-this-button-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

[XSLT works in IE, not in Chrome or Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976383/xslt-works-in-ie-not-in-chrome-or-firefox)

[Why this button works in IE but not in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260598/why-this-button-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

[Javascript works in IE but not in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180489/javascript-works-in-ie-but-not-in-chrome)

[javascript works in IE but not in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033402/javascript-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

but nothing has helped. I'm sure it must be something really simple I'm missing but can't figure it out!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok turns out it was simple, should have been using `location.href` instead of `document.url` for it to work in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

*(This **has** to be a duplicate.)*

`keyCode` is Microsoft-specific. It's `which` on other browsers. So:

```
function checkReturnKey(){
    // Test to see if the return key has been pressed
    if ( (event.keyCode || event.which) == 13 ) {
        login();
    }
}
```

That works because of JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html), which doesn't have a boolean result; instead, its result is the first operand if that operand is *truthy*, or the second operand if not. So if `event.keyCode` is a truthy value (`undefined` is falsy), we compare `13` with that value; if it's falsy (`undefined`, for instance), we compare `event.which` with `13` instead.

I believe you also want to be doing this on `keydown`, not `keypress`; e.g.:

```
<input id="user" type="text" onkeydown="checkReturnKey()"/>
<!-- -----------------------------^^^^                  -->
```

Comment: Thanks, it may indeed be a duplicate but I haven't managed to find anything that helps. Good to know about the keyCode being Microsoft Specific, didn't know that so have amended my code. However, it hasn't resolved the issue as nothing happens upon the keypress of the return or when clicking the button.

Comment: @KT79: Did you see this bit? *"I believe you also want to be doing this on keydown, not keypress."* I've updated the answer to add an example to that sentence (and moved it to the end). Amusingly, I just [answered this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38846778/157247) with something that let me quickly check, and yes, you definitely don't want `keypress` to detect key 13.

Comment: yes sorry saw that as well and amended to that (I definitely didn't want keypress!) but it still doesn't do anything when the return key is pressed or the login button clicked, it's driving me mad! Thanks for your help!